# Как отследить закрытие окна созданного при помощи window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery

имею такой код.

```js
    $('#test').on('click', function() {
        
        var link = $(this).attr("href");
        var x = screen.width/2 - 700/2;
        var y = screen.height/2 - 450/2;
        window.open(link , "about:blank" , 'height=485,width=700,left='+x+',top='+y);
        return false;

    });
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" id="test">Добавить</a>
```

Когда пользователь кликает по ссылке открываеться окно, но как отследить когда пользователь закрил это окно. Например после его закрытия вивести alert();

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону событий `unload` и `beforeunload`.

Comment: @Jigius,  спасибо, это нашел в гугле, пробую сообразить но пока ни как.

Answer (score 1):

У объекта `window` есть свойство `closed`. Как вариант, можно его периодически проверять и в случае изменения выполнять какое-то действие. Подробнее здесь https://itchief.ru/lessons/javascript/javascript-window-object-opening-and-closing#id-10

Comment: Так и сделал.  var wnd = 'тут ссылка'; if (wnd.closed){ alert ("Окно закрыто");   }